# parse date values from Textfile in python

Tags: python

i want to find date-values ( eg. 20.11.2022 oder 20. November 2022 or similar) in a Text
File.
I tried it with the module dateparser or datefinder or regex.

All can find the datevalues. But the trouble begins
when the text file is mixed with numeric values.
For example:
1.234.2333  This is an example Text on 22.01.2022 and stops here

So anyone an idea how to process files where ar also Numerical values inside?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a check after attempting parsing like so:

```
import datetime
if isinstance(x, datetime.date):
   ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression for dates (YYYY-MM-DD) should check for 4 digits at the front of the expression, followed by a hyphen, then a two-digit month between 01 and 12, followed by another hyphen, and finally a two-digit day between 01 and 31.

```
/^\d{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/
```

This code works for most dates but does exclude invalid days of the month like 2021-02-29 (2021 is not a leap year) or 2021-04-31 (April has only 30 days). These checks can be done using datetime module like below

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d1 = "2022-02-29"
>>> datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\*\envs\dj\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\*\envs\dj\lib\_strptime.py", line 534, in _strptime
    julian = datetime_date(year, month, day).toordinal() - \
ValueError: day is out of range for month
>>> d2 = "2020-02-29"
>>> datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 0, 0)
```

When date is not valid then datetime module will throw a ValueError, when parsing text if we get this value error we can skip that record.

```
>>> dates = [d1, d2] # let say re.findall() gives d1 and d2 from text
>>> valid_dates = []
>>> for dt in dates:
...     try:
...             datetime.strptime(dt, "%Y-%m-%d")
...             valid_dates.append(dt)
...     except ValueError:
...             pass
...
datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 29, 0, 0)
>>>
>>> valid_dates
['2020-02-29']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try your regex. I already worked with regex but it seems not good enough.